# 17.04 - proxychains can't resolve DNS

Tags: kubuntu, 17.04, proxy

I am using Kubuntu 17.04 and I installed `proxychains` which worked like a charm on Kali Linux.

In `/etc/proxychains.conf` I commented line that returns `strict_chain` and uncommented line that returns `dynamic_chain`. Everything else is defaulting.

```
dynamic_chain
#
# Dynamic - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# at least one proxy must be online to play in chain
# (dead proxies are skipped)
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
#strict_chain
```

then I ran `proxychain google-chrome` and I would get warnings such as:

```
!!!need more proxies!!!
|DNS-request| www.googleapis.com 
|DNS-response|: clients2.google.com does not exist
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout
```

I also tried these:

```
proxychains curl https://google.com
```

output:

```
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
|DNS-request| google.com 
|D-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<--timeout

!!!need more proxies!!!

|DNS-response|: google.com does not exist
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.com
```

or ping;

```
proxychains ping https://google.com
```

output:

```
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libproxychains.so.3' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ping: https://google.com: Name or service not known
```

Comment: In backtrack , proxychains is using TOR on 127.0.0.1:9050 . Your other errors suggest DNS is not working, so try either specifying an ip such as 8.8.4.4 rather than google or install TOR. IMHO TOR is best installed as part of the tor bundle from the tor project rather than from the ubuntu repos, but up to you.

Comment: @Panther is there a way to make it work by avoiding TOR IP addresses overall? I tried commenting out TOR address and I added `socks4  5.9.212.53 9559 
socks4 89.169.1.81 80
http 221.181.34.74 82 
socks4 61.147.67.2 
`  to the config file. Problem still remains. As for DNS warning, I am also using Kubuntu 17.04 on my laptop which doesn't have this warning but problem above remains.

Comment: Can you ping google.com and 8.8.4.4 ?

Comment: As far as I can determine it requires TOR.

Comment: does not using proxy chains without tor sort of defeat the purpose ? Perhaps I can give you an alternate .

Comment: Try this https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/how-to-use-proxychains-to-redirect-your-traffic-through-proxy-server

Comment: @Panther I will try to ping these when I reach my PC. As for Tor, I tought Tor is just one of many services that provide their proxy. I used proxychains on Kali without any additional installations but that may be just because Kali comes with many tools and configs preinstalled

Comment: OK, good luck to you, I have tried many configuration options and I can not get it working without TOR. Please post a solution if you find one.

Comment: @Panther hey I didn't want to bother with configurations anymore because I only needed proxychains for simple task and I didn't really need true anonymity, so I just did `sudo apt install tor` and everything works well now. Can you post it as answer so we can close this thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, proxychains only works with TOR.

After trying some other options I posted in the comments, the solution was in fact:

```
sudo apt install tor
```

After installing TOR , proxychains works as expected.

Comment: This didn't work for me, same error

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was not completely solved by installing `tor` as explained in [the accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/984227/953371).

After installing `tor`, you need to start the service with the following command:

```
sudo service tor start
```

You can use `systemctl` to start or stop the service:

Examples:

```
sudo systemctl start tor.service
sudo systemctl stop tor.service
```