# proxychains could not resolve host

Tags: networking, proxy

I am trying to configure my proxy for wsl2 (Ubuntu 20.04) so that I can use git on wsl2 in China.

I have a proxy whose proxy is 127.0.0.1:8090 and it works fine on my windows. I followed the tutorial and set `socks5   127.0.0.1   8090` at proxychains.conf but it does not work.

Then I found this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983897/17-04-proxychains-cant-resolve-dns) and installed tor, start it up, but executing `proxychains curl google.com` still gives the following error msgs:

```
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
|DNS-request| google.com
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:7890-<--timeout
|DNS-response|: google.com does not exist
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the IP address from 127.0.0.1 to 172.29.160.1 which is my wsl's ipv4 address got from ipconfig in cmd:
[image]
then everything goes correct:
[image]